# Building Qt 4.7 Windows Mobile 6 ARM

Tags: qt, build, windows-mobile-6

I'm trying to build QT for CE6 using the VS2008 compiler with the Mobile 6 SDK ARM tools.  I'm following the instructions on the Qt site in regards to include locations and my directories seem to match exactly with the exception that I'm on Windows 7, so the program files directory has(x86) inside of it.

Include dirs are
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Mobile 6 SDK\PocketPC\Include\Armv4i
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\ce\include

I configure with:
configure -platform win32-msvc2008 -xplatform wincewm60professional-msvc2008

followed by nmake.

I then get:
tools\qbytearray.cpp(137) : error C3861: 'strcpy_s': identifier not found

If I add some defines around the offending lines, I can get past this point, but then I hit a bunch of

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Mobile 6 SDK\PocketPC\Include\Armv4i\types.h(59)
: error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'

It seems that this build platform should be well supported and I'm a bit baffled how the strcpy_s thing would even be there.

Is anyone getting this to compile with the standard CE6 SDK?  Do I need to use a custom SDK for our platform to get this to compile?

I'd also be curious if anyone has webkit running on mobile 6.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I've discovered that I can build the Qt library on my home PC but not on my work PC, including webkit (though I had about a million C4291 and C4344 warnings).

Comment: There must be some difference in my CE build environment, maybe SP1 not installed - I haven't been able to track it down yet.